# что означает это строка кода *(*(p = new double*) = new double) = 2;

Tags: c++, указатели

что означает это строка кода `*(*(p = new double*) = new double) = 2;`

Answer (score 9):

```
*(*(p = new double*) = new double) = 2;
```

Начнем с внутренней скобки

```
p = new double*
```

В переменную `p` записывается адрес памяти, выделенной для указателя `double*`, и само выражение имеет значение этого указателя.

```
*(p = new double*) = new double
```

Здесь оно разыменовывается и по адресу, который хранится в `p`, записывается значение указателя, выделенного под переменную `double`, каковое значение - указателя на `double` - и возвращается, а затем разыменовывается и в него уже записывается значение 2...

Т.е. картинка выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо,просто начал искать задачи на указатели в с++ пока еще не особо понял как пользоваться

Answer (score 4):

Если расписать элементарные действия по отдельности, то получится

```
p = new double *;
*p = new double;
**p = 2;
```

У вас все то же самое "свёрнуто" в одно выражение.

Разумеется, все это имеет смысл только если переменная `p` объявлена заранее и объявлена с правильным типом.

Comment: спасибо,просто начал искать задачи на указатели в с++ пока еще не особо понял как пользоваться